# Apache virtual hosts configuration works on Windows, not on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

On Windows this Apache virtual host configuration is fine, but when on Linux it does not work the same.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/chess/htdocs"
    ServerName www.c.com
    ServerAlias www.c.com

    php_value include_path .;/www/chess/htdocs/includes
    ErrorLog "logs/chess-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/chess-access.log" common

  <Directory "/www/chess/htdocs"> 
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory> 

    AddType application/x-compress .Z 
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
    AddType audio/x-ms-wma .wma 
    AddType application/octet-stream .jar .class 

    DefaultType application/x-httpd-php 

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
</VirtualHost>
```

Why would it work on a Windows environment but fail to configure properly on a Linux machine?

Comment: Any chance it's as simple as not in /var/www ?

Comment: This question is perfect for http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is the Windows path separator. In Linux it's the colon (`:`).

Comment: Sneaky. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no quotes around `.;/www/chess/htdocs/includes` and you should use colons to separate folder paths.